# Can't call wget from Python script

Tags: bash, python, wget

I am writing this script that executes a bunch of commands one of which is to download some packages from a certain url.

Following is my script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#! /usr/bin/env bash

import os 
import sys 
import subprocess


url = sys.argv[1] 
getRpm = "'wget %s' %url"
searchRpm = "rpm -qa|grep sys.*"
execsCmds = [getRpm,searchRpm]

def runCommands(commands=execsCmds):
    for cmd in execsCmds:
        print "Running Command"
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

runCommands()
```

When I execute is it says:

```
/bin/sh: wget %s: command not found
```

Comment: Sidenote: "#! /usr/bin/env bash" is obsolete. Either this a python-script or a bash-script. It can't be both.

Comment: Where do you tell wget what is to be inserted in %s and %url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line that constructs `getRpm` should probably be:

```
getRpm = 'wget %s' %url
```

Basically, just remove the extra double-quotes.